# How can I read an image into OpenCV directly from the clipboard or from the screen?

Tags: macos, opencv, opencv3.0

I'm looking for some way to read images that originate from either the screen or are in the clipboard (OS X in my case), without having to first save them into a local file.

OpenCV's `imread` method seems to only allow loading files.

Is there any clever way to get the clipboard image and/or the current screen to be read?